# What does 티격태격 mean?

Tags: translation, meaning, phrase-meaning

It's from a song and I don't really understand every translation I've seen. The whole verse/sentence goes like 막상 **티격태격** 서로를 향해 겨누지만 고마운 줄 모르고 배부른 거지 뭐. (for context)

I'd be glad if someone helped me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

티격태격 is a common onomatopoeic adverb describing two people quarreling, usually in a trifling way rather than seriously (You can also say 티격태격하다, to quarrel).

e.g. 아이들이 늘 티격태격 싸운다 = The children always fight with each other.

막상 티격태격 서로를 향해 겨누지만 고마운 줄 모르고 배부른 거지 뭐.
= They quibble and go after each other, taking what they have for granted rather than being grateful for them.